# How to post multipart/form-data in uwp using flurl

Tags: uwp, flurl

I'm using flurl in uwp, and want to post an image file to the server.

The server api needs a parameter "image_file", a binary file, need to post using multipart/form-data.

Now I have a StorageFile, how to post it?

```
string res = "";
        try
        {
            res = await _detect_api_url
                   .PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
                   .AddStringParts(new { api_key = _api_key, api_secret = _api_secret, return_landmark = returnLandmarks, return_attributes = returnAttributes })
                   .AddFile("image_file", imageFile)
                   ).ReceiveString();
        }
        catch (FlurlHttpTimeoutException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("FlurlHttp internal time out.");
            res = "FlurlHttp internal time out.";
        }
        catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            res = ex.Call.ErrorResponseBody;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I have a StorageFile, how to post it?

The `AddFile` has two overload methods:

```
public CapturedMultipartContent AddFile(string name, Stream stream, string fileName, string mediaType = null, int bufferSize = 4096);
public CapturedMultipartContent AddFile(string name, string path, string mediaType = null, int bufferSize = 4096);
```

So that you can provide a file stream or the file local path for the method to post file to the server. For how to read the file stream from the [`StorageFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files). And for the local file path you can directly get it by `StorageFile.Path` property. Pay attention that you cannot directly provide a local path build by yourself, you must get it from a `StorageFile` object, details about this please reference [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Following is the sample code for posting a file by `AddFile` methods.

```
string _detect_api_url = "http://localhost/BackgroundTransferSample/Upload.aspx";
private async void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/picture0.png"));
    IBuffer buffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(imageFile);
    string res = "";
    try
    {
        //AddFile by file stream.
        res = await _detect_api_url
               .PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
               .AddFile("image_file", buffer.AsStream(), "imagefile.png", null, (int)buffer.Length)
               ).ReceiveString();

        //AddFile by local file path.
        //res = await _detect_api_url
        //     .PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
        //     .AddFile("image_file", imageFile.Path)
        //     ).ReceiveString();
    }
    catch (FlurlHttpTimeoutException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FlurlHttp internal time out.");
        res = "FlurlHttp internal time out.";
    }
    catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        res = ex.Call.ErrorResponseBody;
    }
}
```